# Trying to get a Java function to return an array based on a string parameter passed to it

Tags: java, arrays

Here's what I am trying to do; I am trying to write a small program that uses a function to get an array containing the members of a department based on the department selected. There are about 40 departments, and each department has 1 to 4 members. So this what I did, but I can't seem to resolve to a variable:

From main:

```
String[]names = initial(department)
```

Departments is the name of the department being passed to the function. In the function I have:

```
public static String[] initial (String responsibleDepartment) {

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Accounts Receivable")) {
        String[] assignInitial = {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"}
     }

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Customer Service")) {
        String[] assignInitial = {"Mary Wexler", "Turd Ferguson"}
     }

   // and 38 more if statements with the rest of the departments. Finally I have:
        return assignInitial;
        }
```

So the way it stands, "assignInitial cannot be resolved to a variable" (that's what it says by the return statement.) If I try to initialize the variable before the first "if" statement, and then remove the initialization of String[] next to the assignInitial in the first "if" statement, then it says "Array constants can only be used in initializers." I am sure there is a better way to do this, but I can't seem to make any headway with what I am found online. Any takers?

Thank you much!
-The Munch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring each `String[] assignInitial` inside an `if` statements, so the scope of that variable is local to the `if` statement. Outside of the `if` statements, that variable is not declared.

To fix this, pull the declaration out of the `if` scope and into the method scope. You'll have to add `new String[]` in front of each array since array constants can only be used in initializers.

```
public static String[] initial (String responsibleDepartment) {

String[] assignInitial = null;

if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Accounts Receivable")) {
    // Note the new String[] below
    assignInitial = new String[] {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"};
 }

if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Customer Service")) {
    assignInitial = new String[] {"Mary Wexler", "Turd Ferguson"};
 }

// Other if statements here

return assignInitial;
```

Note that there might be other, easier ways to find the values for `assignInitial` than this series of `if` statements. For example, you could built a `switch` statement or a `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: "Array constants can only be used in initializers."

Comment: You're right -- give me a minute to update my answer.

Comment: This compiles now -- sorry about that, I had glossed over the array constants. The code was also missing semicolons at the end of lines so make sure you remember those.

Comment: OK I am gonna try this now - 40 depts to do so it will take a bit. Thank you! And sorry about the semis (I always forget those :-) )

Comment: Yep! It worked! (Except I had to do String[] assignInitial = null;) in line 3 but other than that, great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Since no one has suggested it yet, Java supports switches with Strings, you don't need a bunch of if-statements. You can use a switch, which is slightly faster if you have that many if-statements.

```
switch(responsibleDepartment) {

  case "Accounts Receivable":
    return new String[]{"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"};
  ...
```

Alternatively you could also create a Map and build the map and just access the map like this

```
map.get(responsibleDepartment) // Returns {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"}
```

If you need it concurrent use ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: Oh that sounds neat! I have the program written but i have another one I have to write and I am going to try your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the variable and then assign the value to be accessible outside the if condition. Or you can return the variable right after you create it to stop the flow of the method if you don't need to do anything else in the function.

```
public static String[] initial (String responsibleDepartment) {
    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Accounts Receivable")) {
        String[] assignInitial = {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"};
        return assignInitial;
    }  

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Customer Service")) {
        String[] assignInitial = {"Mary Wexler", "Turd Ferguson"}
        return assignInitial;
    }
    // and 38 more if statements with the rest of the departments. Finally I have:
    return null;
    }
```

If you define the variable inside the if context, it is not available to be returned after the context is completed.

Comment: "Array constants can only be used in initializers."

Comment: Updated the answer with another approach.

Comment: I did a different answer that worked, but I want to try yours as well. Can you mark 2 answers as correct? (I'm a n00b here, not sure how this all works)

Comment: No you cannot. Don't worry about marking it correct. You should mark the one that works best for your use case. If my answer works, I would appreciate an up vote. Thanks :)

Comment: I gave you the upvote! Because I already marked a different answer as correct I'm going to leave it as is, but that one and your solution work equally well! In fact I have to generate another array from a method called "final" and I am using your solution in that one so I have both ways to do it in the future. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, initial assignInitial outside conditions and use variable in all places.

```
public static String[] initial (String responsibleDepartment) {
    String[] assignInitial = null;

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Accounts Receivable")) {
        assignInitial = {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"}
     }

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Customer Service")) {
        assignInitial = {"Mary Wexler", "Turd Ferguson"}
     }

   // and 38 more if statements with the rest of the departments. Finally I have:
        return assignInitial;
        }
```

Comment: "Array constants can only be used in initializers."

Comment: Then change like this if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Accounts Receivable")) {
       String[] assignInitial = {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"};
       return assignInitial;
     }

Comment: Infact you can return the array of string in each if conditions.

Comment: So far I don't have any error messages, so that seems like it might have worked (I'll know in a few mins)... but why did it work?

Comment: Nope, error message. OK so now here is what it is doing - I don't have a final "return" statement (after all the if statements), so it is saying "Method must return a result of type String[] which I know it is doing ... but I don't think IT knows that.

Comment: at the end you can return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way and skip the whole variable thing. If it doesn't match anything it will return an empty array.

```
public static String[] initial (String responsibleDepartment) {

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Accounts Receivable")) {
        return new String[] {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"};
     }

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Customer Service")) {
         return new String[] {"Mary Wexler", "Turd Ferguson"};
     }

    return new String[] {};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this little change, to make the code more readable and not abuse the return:

```
public static String[] initial (String responsibleDepartment) {
    String[] names = null;

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Accounts Receivable")) {
        names = new String[] {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"};
     }

    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Customer Service")) {
        names = new String[] {"Mary Wexler", "Turd Ferguson"};
     }

    return names;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code:

(1) The **scope of the variable `assignInitial`** is limited within the `if` blocks, so you can't use it outside the `if` block

(2) Also, **use `else if`** as shown below instead of many `if` conditions (If you don't use `else if`, all the 38 other `if` conditions will be evaluated which is unnecessary)

```
public static String[] initial (String responsibleDepartment) {
    String[] assignInitial = null;
    if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Accounts Receivable")) {
        assignInitial = new String[] {"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"};
    } else if (responsibleDepartment.equals("Customer Service")) {
        assignInitial = new String[] {"Mary Wexler", "Turd Ferguson"};
    } // and 38 more if statements with the rest of the departments.
   return assignInitial;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're taking the wrong approach here.

Your entire method is fundamentally doing exactly the same thing as a `Map`: "given *this* (String) input, what resulting (array of Strings) output does it map to?"

So as an exact rewrite of your existing code, I would first do this:

```
private static final Map<String, String[]> INITIALS_BY_DEPARTMENT;

static {
    INITIALS_BY_DEPARTMENT = new HashMap<>();
    INITIALS_BY_DEPARTMENT.put("Accounts Receivable", new String[]{"Mike Davis", "Ben Jones", "Ann Smith"});
    INITIALS_BY_DEPARTMENT.put("Customer Service", new String[]{"Mary Wexler", "Turd Ferguson"});
    // other assignments
}

public static String[] initial (String responsibleDepartment) {
    return INITIALS_BY_DEPARTMENT.get(responsibleDepartment);
}
```

---

There's still a bad smell with this code, which is that you have *data* mixed up in your logic.  Ideally, there would be some external database or other configuration that defined which people were responsible for each department.  Instead of defining a constant map in your code, you would read this into that map at startup.  This way you haven't hardcoded values, and you don't run the risk of falling out of date with reality.

Sometimes of course this isn't possible, and the information is purely internal to your application.  But for the use case implied here, the mappings from departments to users is almost certainly defined in *some* external system.  Even if you're not able to read from that right now, at least separate your mappings into a config file, and have a loader to read that.  This way you have separated your data from the logic, and can easily switch to reading from a different source in future.